# Command failed with exit code 1 during create-react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am using first time react I have done everything that was written in the documentation but when i execute the yarn start after create-react-app it is started showing the following errors

[image]

please tell me the solution asap .

Comment: Firstly, please post the error as text, not as an image.  Some people on Stack Overflow are visually impaired and use screenreaders, and a screenreader won't be able to read the text in the image.  Secondly, please don't write 'asap' or 'urgent' or anything like that, as it comes across as rude.  Your question is no more important to answer than anyone else's here.

Comment: Try removing spaces from your directory names. It shouldn't cause a problem but there is a chance that it might